# Production deployment issue on Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google App engine and deployed web application.
I tried to deploy code on local using App engine then it is working fine 
but when I deployed on Production server then it caused error.

```
Request : POST 20180909t164211-dot-spry-autumn-140509.appspot.com/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs 

(View request) Status : 500 Internal Server Error, Updated Screen shots for error and web.xml configration.

Web.xml configration: 
     <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>services</param-name>
                <param-value />
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Production error :

[image: Image shows exception occurs on production server.]

Please suggest me some solutions for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoints v1 has been shut down. You must migrate your application to Endpoints v2. See [migration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your suggestion, I followed same and now no exception.But I am not get any Values from server. As I checked Logs then below Warning I saw :

2018-09-17 15:54:05.318 IST
[s~spry-autumn-140509/20180917t155213.412633544762062087].<stderr>: api.twitter.com
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=a6c11b97 or
 http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=64f416b2
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[a6c11b97-64f416b2 d82b1369-398ebb55], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.1}